# ETH mysteriously removed from my account around 12hours after using Binance Bridge

Tags: ether, metamask, wallets, binance

Perhaps someone can shed some light on this for me?

Recently joined the crypto world. Created a Metamask account, sent some test eth, all was fine. Had a family member send some BNB, then add some pegged ether from Binance to my account. Added BSC to Metamask, then used Binance bridge to convert it from BSC-pegged eth to Ethereum Mainnet.

All went fine. Eth was showing ( around $700 worth ). 12 Hours later it was transferred out.

The odd thing I find is, the account that the ETH was sent to, that's the only thing on that account. The only activity, the only thing that account has ever done. If I search back using the logs on etherscan, and say I set a date for August, its defaults back to September the 5th, so this account seems to have been created around the same time I used the bridge.
As an I.T senior and a field I work in, I know what's safe, links, all the don't do's . I followed this extremely strictly. However, this has happened.

I have had a look on forums, other sites, and checked out addresses of scammers and accounts where stolen funds go, they are active, and have many in and out transactions. Not this one, this account has that one sole transaction, and the ETH is just still there.

My question is, could it be some holding account? Any thoughts and ideas would be greatly appreciated.

To answer a few possible questions, No I don't have a Ledger yet unfortunately. All my software is licensed, no cracked software, no extensions downloaded from not original sites, passwords, seeds, all the juicy stuff encrypted, and removed off pc onto flash drive, nothing saved in plaintext, when I need a password I fire up an old laptop not connected to the net to retrieve the passwords. Essentially a clean OS ( Windows 10 ) using Brave Browser.

The wallets public address in question is 0x0A8744a230f606f784aB7908e965746cBbE80a9D
The TXID is 0x30b0f73e7bf2d147ff0126cc56bb99624abb6cd9a358e063c6da08ed73f2e9f3

Any and all info will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you generate the seed phrase/private key? Did you share it with someone else? The funds moved due to gas prices it doesn't look like a bot. In similar cases the problem was using the seed phrase in a dubious site, or malware installed through play store or the browser, this doesn't seems to be your case, so perhaps did you inadvertently share the key, but that is really hard to verify.

Comment: HI @Ismael. Thank you for your reply. I use a separate computer I set up just for this cause, to use as my "crypto PC". I have Windows 10 installed, Brave browser, and the extensions are Metamask, Binance wallet and Ronin wallet. Site history is also very limited, opensea, axie infinity, zed run, rarity tools, binance bridge, and gmail. I see the funds have been transfered from that account into another account yesterday, this is a hackers account for sure, as this account has transactions in and out often.  I hint of where the breach may have happened is -

Comment: there are multiple transactions on Ronin bridge for axies, SLP and ASX. I Have traced this back, after much research, this is an account linked to the name "babygirl" on Ronin. But it goes deeper. Babygirl seems to buy a lot, and get transferred alot from another specific address. this address, the user actually named his name on Ronin. I have linked it to a name. It belongs to a Data Systems Engineer base din the Philippines. After cross referencing and doing a lot of searching and tagging, I even found his linden profile. I have reported it to Ronin and Axie, but they don't seem to care

Comment: I've seen a similar report involving a ronin wallet. I'm not familiar with the project, but due to its popularity there will be scam wallets for sure. Check the official procedures, don't take shortcuts, don't follow browser links or discord chats.